# Data points on google scatter chart with static polygon

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm creating a dashboard that needs to show the current temp/humidity of a sensor on a chart and display it in relation to a defined static polygon.  The polygon represents the acceptable temp/humidity area.  I do not need to show previous values, just current temp/humidity point.

I'm trying to create something like this: [image]

What google chart can accommodate something like this?  Is there a better library that can handle this?  I can display the data with a scatter chart but I'm not sure how to approach the polygon:

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Humidity', 'Temp'],
          [ 51,      68],
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Temp Humidity ',
          hAxis: {title: 'Relative Humidity', minValue: 45, maxValue: 65},
          vAxis: {title: 'Temperature (F)', minValue: 64, maxValue: 80},
          legend: 'none'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sr825wjb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `ComboChart`, with a line series for the polygon.

add a third column for the polygon's y-axis values.
then add rows for each corner of the poylgon,
with one additional row to connect the polygon back to the first corner.

use `null` for the column values of the "other" series.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Humidity', 'Temp', 'poly'],
  // scatter point
  [51, 68, null],

  // polygon
  [54, null, 70],
  [58, null, 70],
  [58, null, 72],
  [54, null, 72],
  [54, null, 70],
]);
```

in the options, set the series options as follows...

```
var options = {
  title: 'Temp Humidity ',
  hAxis: {title: 'Relative Humidity', minValue: 45, maxValue: 65},
  vAxis: {title: 'Temperature (F)', minValue: 64, maxValue: 80},
  legend: 'none',
  seriesType: 'scatter',
  series: {
    1: {
      color: '#000000',
      type: 'line'
    }
  }
};
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Humidity', 'Temp', 'poly'],
    // scatter point
    [51, 68, null],

    // polygon
    [54, null, 70],
    [58, null, 70],
    [58, null, 72],
    [54, null, 72],
    [54, null, 70],
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Temp Humidity ',
    hAxis: {title: 'Relative Humidity', minValue: 45, maxValue: 65},
    vAxis: {title: 'Temperature (F)', minValue: 64, maxValue: 80},
    legend: 'none',
    seriesType: 'scatter',
    series: {
      1: {
        color: '#000000',
        type: 'line'
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```